# zip file is zipping to default project dir folder rather than file dir

Tags: python, zip

my code is :

```
    def zip_file(path, zip_file_name ,root):
    ziph = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    ziph.write(path, arcname= os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(zip_file_name)[0]))
    #os.remove(path)
    ziph.close()

def zip_dir(dir_to_zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_zip):
        for curr_file in files:
            fullFilePath = os.path.join(root, curr_file)
            if not curr_file.endswith('.zip'):
                zip_file(fullFilePath, "{}.zip".format(fullFilePath), root)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    zip_dir('C:\\Users\\My_namne\\Desktop\\TEST')
```

I want it to zip the file to the original folder, but it zips to work dir of my project all of the files. How to change the dir of output archive? now it zip to my working directory and the zip the entire root to path

Comment: Have you tried inspecting/printing the `path` argument for `zip_file`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: yes it sais C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\TEST\backup1.py

Comment: can you try this `ziph = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path,zip_file_name), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def zip_file(filename):
    zip_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.zip'
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w')
    f.write(filename, os.path.basename(filename), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    f.close()
    return zip_filename


def zip_dir(dir_to_zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_zip):
        for curr_file in files:
            fullFilePath = os.path.join(root, curr_file)
            if not curr_file.endswith('.zip'):
                zip_file(fullFilePath)
```

this works

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `zipfile.ZipFile` should be the complete path to the archive you are creating. Make the change in `zip_dir`

```
def zip_dir(dir_to_zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_zip):
        for curr_file in files:
            fpath = os.path.join(root, curr_file)
            zip_file(fpath, "{}.zip".format(fpath),root)
```

---

This will create an archive for each file in its directory. The archive will only contain the file itself, not the file's entire path.

```
import os, zipfile
def zip_file(filepath, zipfilepath ,curr_file):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilepath, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as ziph:
        ziph.write(filepath, arcname=curr_file)

def zip_dir(dir_to_zip):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_zip):
        for curr_file in files:
            if not curr_file.endswith('.zip'):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, curr_file)
                zipfilepath = "{}.zip".format(filepath)
                zip_file(filepath, zipfilepath, curr_file)
```